# TP-Link TL-WN881ND v1.0

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I have problem with the TP-Link TL-WN881ND v1.0. I can´t connect to wifi. When i try to connect after few seconds  "Connection Failed" error message is displayed.  I have installed a Github drivers https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi_new but it´s not working.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What is the model of your computer and which version of Ubuntu you have in it?

Comment: i have a dell optiplex-7010 i5-3470 and ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: The git driver probably worked with Ubuntu 20.04, kernel > 5.15. Detail [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263714) Remove the git driver and install a new one from the official. `sudo apt install firmware-realtek` Another useful document [here](https://authmane512.medium.com/how-to-install-a-missing-firmware-on-linux-debian-21c0a9213c56), but yours is rtl8192ee.